# How to check for duplicate 'ofstream' objects in a vector of shared pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, file-io, smart-pointers, std

In a practice project, I'm learning async/threading methodology as well as the concept for service type classes. I have a vector of shared pointers to ofstream objects, but am lost as to how to check for duplicates within that vector.

For clarification, I'm opting to have a single log file per module of my project, but in the event that two ofstream objects are added for the same file can cause mangling in outputs. I've tried a few different ways to compare between them, but I can't figure out the standard method of doing so. There also doesn't seem to be very much information on the subject, or perhaps I missed something basic in which I will slap myself for missing.

I know 'i' is accessing the objects in the vector, but cannot seem to get this to compile. Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

```
class LoggerService
{
public: 
    ...
private:
    ...
    bool add_log_file(const std::string& file)
    {
        bool is_duplicate = false;
        for (int i : *ofstreams_) // <------ This block.
        {
            if (file.c_str() == i)
            {
                is_duplicate = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!is_duplicate)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            ofstreams_.push_back(std::make_shared<std::ofstream>(file.c_str()));
            return true;
        }
    }
    ...
    static std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::ofstream>> ofstreams_;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt there is a standard way to get the path of an open ofstream. How about instead of a vector you have a map of file->ofstream. Or make your own class that contains path and ofstream and put those in the vector

Comment: I like the idea of having a map, I'll give that a shot. Could you let me know why you -1'd my ask? I just didn't realize there wasn't a way at all to compare ofstream objects without preliminary data.

Comment: i did not -1 the question